# Calculate the number of laminations in the transformer

Tags: transformer

A core-type transformer, is constructed with \$0.014\$ in. thick laminations having a uniform width of \$2.75\$ in. If the maximum flux and flux density are respectively, \$6.2 x 10^8\$ maxwells and \$ 8.2 x 10^8\$ maxwells per square inch and the air space between laminations occupies 8 percent of the stacked core, Calculate the number of laminations in the transformer. Answer is 197

So I just started this chapter with transformer, first I tried unit analysis. So I multiplied \$ 8.2 x 10^8\$ maxwells per inches squared to \$2.75^2\$ and 0.08 divided it by \$6.2 x 10^8\$ maxwells and then finally divided it by the thickness. However, my answer is not even close to 197. But I think my solution kinda makes sense. Please show solution.

So \$\frac{8.2 x 10^8 Maxwells/inch^2(2.75)^2inch^{2}(0.8)}{6.2x 10^8Maxwells}\$ then divided by the thickness 0.014 inch. I got 57 only

Comment: If you ask the question again after having cast it in sensible units like metres and Tesla, I might be minded to think about it. If you have an answer, show it and your working, 'not even close' does not show what you've done.

Comment: 2.75^2 is wrong, that's the width of a lamination. Area of lam = 2.75*0.014 = 0.0385in2. Area of core = flux/density = 6.2/8.2 = 0.75in2. Therefore Nlams = corearea/lamarea = 0.75/0.0385 = 19.6. Off by a factor of 10. I suspect the flux is 6.2e9 maxwells, rather than 6.2e8. Interstingly, a square core stack of 2.75 is also 2.75/0.014 = 196 lams, but square is not stated in the question, though square is a common transformer shape. Neither coincidental similar sum allows for the 8% airspace. Check the provenance of your question.